# Maven : Getting compilation error using the Install command through cmd

Tags: java

[Compilation error on using Maven Install command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rAAO.png)

Hi , When I use the Maven clean command it runs successfully but when I run the install command , I have been getting compilation errors . Follwing is the error I have been getting.Thanks

```
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building TigerFinal 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ TigerFinal ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\Shashank_bisht\workspace\TigerFinal\target
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.517 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-01-04T22:53:12+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/105M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\Shashank_bisht\workspace\TigerFinal>mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building TigerFinal 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ TigerFinal ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Shashank_bisht\workspace\TigerFinal\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ TigerFinal ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 11 source files to C:\Users\Shashank_bisht\workspace\TigerFinal\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Shashank_bisht/workspace/TigerFinal/src/main/java/tiger/MyHomepage/Home.java:[11,27] packa
MyHomepageTestCases does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Shashank_bisht/workspace/TigerFinal/src/main/java/tiger/Utils/AppUtils.java:[14,27] packag
yHomepageTestCases does not exist
[INFO] 2 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.733 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-01-04T22:53:26+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/153M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile)
project TigerFinal: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Shashank_bisht/workspace/TigerFinal/src/main/java/tiger/MyHomepage/Home.java:[11,27] packa
MyHomepageTestCases does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Shashank_bisht/workspace/TigerFinal/src/main/java/tiger/Utils/AppUtils.java:[14,27] packag
yHomepageTestCases does not exist
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: `mvn clean` just deletes the target folder by default. Of course that succeeds. 'install' runs the full lifecycle, including compile. You apparently have some Java compilation errors. Have you tried building the project in your IDE? that should show you the errors

Comment: Hi Sean , you want me to run the pom.xml file in IDE and check into the console for errors?

Comment: No, let the IDE build the project, independent of Maven. All major IDEs can import Maven projects correctly

Comment: [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
  C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\..\lib\tools.jar
Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
In most cases you can change the location of your Java
installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.Getting this error also when I have set the goals to install

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

You need a full JDK (Java Development Kit), not a JRE (Java Runtime Environment)

Download a JDK from OpenJDK or Oracle, then [set the environment variable](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) `JAVA_HOME` to the root folder of your JDK.

Then re-try your Maven command

Comment: run "mvn -version" on the command line and check whether the "java home" line of the output points to a jdk